# Filtering instance templates using labels in GCP fails with ''Invalid list filter expression."

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform

Running this python code to list the instance template which have a specific label . Calling the GCP API but fails .

Code Snippet :

```
request = service.instanceTemplates().list(project=project,filter=
    {
        labels: {'env':'dmittal-dc'}
    }
)
```

Tried specifing the value of filter in multiple ways but did not worked:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/dlpx-dcoa-dmittal/global/instanceTemplates?filter=%7B%3Cmodule+%27pip._vendor.webencodings.labels%27+from+%27%2FUsers%2Fdeepali.mittal%2Fdevops-gate%2Fdcenter%2Fpython%2Fbuild%2Fdmittal%2Fvirtual-env36%2Flib%2Fpython3.6%2Fsite-packages%2Fpip%2F_vendor%2Fwebencodings%2Flabels.py%27%3E%3A+%7B%27env%27%3A+%27dmittal-dcoa%27%7D%7D&alt=json returned "Invalid value for field 'filter': '{<module 'pip._vendor.webencodings.labels' from '/Users/deepali.mittal/devops-gate/dcenter/python/build/dmittal/virtual-env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/webencodings/labels.py'>: {'env': 'dmittal-dcoa'}}'. Invalid list filter expression.". Details: "Invalid value for field 'filter': '{<module 'pip._vendor.webencodings.labels' from '/Users/deepali.mittal/devops-gate/dcenter/python/build/dmittal/virtual-env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/webencodings/labels.py'>: {'env': 'dmittal-dc'}}'. Invalid list filter expression.">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` is expected to be of a string type (see `help(service.instanceTemplates().list)` and [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceTemplates/list#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS.filter)). I believe, what you are looking for is this:

```
req = service.instanceTemplates().list(
  project=project,
  filter='properties.labels.env=dmittal-dc'
)
```

Comment: I tried for list instances 
result = compute.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone, filter="metadata.labels.service_type=agent").execute()

However, this is still showing same error 

I tried removing `properties` tag from it 
Replaced `properties`  with `metadata`
replaced `=` with `:`
neither of those fetch the results for me, rather it kept giving me same 400 error